# How to handle multiple response with retrofit - Android

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, retrofit2.6

With retrofit I get response `LevelsEntity` but if I get error it get me `ResponseError`, NOTE: I cant merge `LevelsEntity` and `ResponseError` together in one entity.

LevelsEntity:

```
class LevelsEntity : ArrayList<LevelsEntityItem>()
```

LevelsEntityItem:

```
data class LevelsEntityItem(
    @SerializedName("category")
    val category: Int? = null,
    @SerializedName("completed")
    val completed: Boolean? = null,
    @SerializedName("completionhascriteria")
    val completionhascriteria: Boolean? = null
)
```

ResponseError:

```
data class ResponseError(
    @SerializedName("errorcode")
    val errorcode: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("exception")
    val exception: String? = null,
    @SerializedName("message")
    val message: String? = null
)
```

And I create bellow class for get multiple data like bellow:

```
class BaseLevelsEntity<LevelsEntity, ResponseError> {
    var levelsEntity: LevelsEntity? = null
    var responseError: ResponseError? = null
    val isSuccess: Boolean
        get() = responseError == null
}
```

And in my `@POST` of retrofit is:

```
@POST("/webservice/rest/server.php")
suspend fun getPopularLevelsInLessonsF(
    @Query("mdwsrestformat") mdwsrestformat: String?,
    @Field("wsfunction") wsfunction: String?,
    @Field("wstoken") wstoken: String?,
    @Field("userid") userid: Int?
): Call<BaseLevelsEntity<LevelsEntity, ResponseError>>
```

But I cant get any result in my `impl`:

```
class LessonsRepositoryImpl(
    private val lessonsRemoteDatasource: LessonsRemoteDatasource
) : LessonsRepository {
    override suspend fun getLevelsInLessonsF(
        wstoken: String,
        userid: Int
    ): Resource<BaseLevelsEntity<LevelsEntity, ResponseError>> {
        return responseToResource(lessonsRemoteDatasource.getLevelsValueInLessonsF(wstoken, userid).execute())
    }

    private fun responseToResource(response: Response<BaseLevelsEntity<LevelsEntity, ResponseError>>): Resource<BaseLevelsEntity<LevelsEntity, ResponseError>> {

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            if (response.body() != null) {
                response.body()?.let { result ->
                    if (!result.levelsEntity.isNullOrEmpty()) {
                        if (result.levelsEntity!!.size > 0) {
                            return Resource.Success(result)
                        }
                    } else if (result.responseError != null) {
                        return Resource.Error(result.responseError?.errorcode ?: "unknown")
                    }
                }
            } else {
                return Resource.Error("unknown_info")
            }
        }
        return Resource.Error(response.message())
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this handle from backend API side? I think response always should be in one structured manner. Response should contain code, message, data as a base then if success then code:200, message:success, data:you should get whole array of data and if failure then code:errorcode, message: errormessage, data:no need

Answer (score 1):

Normally response should be in common format.

If cannot do this from backend then you can receive response as `JsonObject` and then check the key manually in repository to decide if it is success or error response. Based on that you can then convert the response to object with gson.